# Using FPDF, can I chain PDF reports?

Tags: fpdf

I have PHP Code which works fine if I comment out one of the two lines below:
$pdf2->Output($filename2,'D'); **This gives me report #1**

$pdf->Output($output_filename,'D'); **This gives me report #2**

- I'd like to just have them run in succession.

Question: Is there a way to chain them so I'll get the download dialog box twice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't send 2 PDFs to the browser in the same HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks Olivier. That's what I thought, but I don't know everything so I thought I would ask. If your last name starts with "P", I want to thank you for what  you've given the PHP World. Expect something in you Christmas stocking from me this year.

Comment: Thanks, you guessed correctly ;-)